# Unable to add docker GPG key via apt-key

Tags: ubuntu, docker, curl

i enter a command for add docker's official GPG key but i don't have OK in output.

The command is :

```
$ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: What output do you have then ?

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: precisely I have no output, the cursor blinks in giving output ...

Comment: Do you think this is related to the proxy I have configured ?

Comment: you tried to verify the GPG key? - `sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88`

Comment: Yes I checked of course, but it comes back to the command line as if I did not type anything.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer After a long wait I received this error in output :

curl : (28) Connection timed out after 300293 milliseconds
gpg : no valid OpenPGP data found.

Comment: remove `| sudo apt-key add -`, and add -v to curl, and after curl has finished, execute `echo $?` - and post all the output

Comment: @hanshenrik Thank you for answer,

Comment: @hanshenrik Thank you for answer.
I am on ubuntu server so I can't post the output in copy / paste.
I post it to you with my hands.I have this output :

* Trying 2600: 9000: 2047: 9200: 3: db06: 4200: 93a1 ...
Immediate connect fail for 2600: 9000: 2074: 9200: 3: db06: 4200: 93a1: Network is unreachable

It is a line of several lines that I received in output.my IP address is 172.29.101.182 and I use a proxy that has the address 172.16.1.2:8080.

Comment: @HassineH'maied run `sudo apt install pastebinit` , then `curl -v https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg 2>&1 | pastebinit` - but i can already guess what's happened here, you don't have a direct connection to the internet, you need to go through a proxy, but your proxy isn't set up for ipv6, curl try to connect via ipv6, and gets blocked by the firewall or router or whatever. try `curl --ipv4 --verbose https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -` , that should force curl to use ipv4

Comment: That's works. I fix it with modify file /etc/environment and put it an export command : http_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
https_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
ftp_proxy="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"
HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
FTP_PROXY="http://proxy.example.com:8080"
NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,localaddress,.localdomain.com"

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is an old question, but hope this helps someone.

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 18.04. 
In my case the error was:

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

What solved the issue for me was running the command below to gain root access:

```
sudo su -
```

With root privileges, I once again ran:

```
root@hostname:~# curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Root access is not necessary to complete the rest of the Docker installation steps.

To leave the root shell either type `exit`, or press CTRL + D.

Comment: This will cause an error if doing it non-interatively

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue as well, but the output showed me that I have to use *root* user instead of *superuser*:

`E: This command can only be used by root.`

And once I logged in with *root* user, I can successfully use the original command with the response on my window:

`OK`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it can help, but I had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 lts and what allowed me to install docker was following:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
but in step 1, replacing the `curl` command with a `sudo curl`and re-running the 3 first commands. I don't measure really the impacts though...
htp

```bash
# Add Docker's official GPG key:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg
sudo install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

# Add the repository to Apt sources:
echo \
  "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
  "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
```